# log4Net XmlHierarchyConfigurator

Tags: c#, log4net

Am using Log4Net in my code,it start throwing this weird exception when my process run.

Here is my Appconfig for Log4Net,still am not sure what am missing here

It throws like

> log4net:Error XmlHierarchyConfigurator : cannot find property[maxSizeRollBackups] to set object on [log4net.Appender.FileAppender].

Config:

```
<appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
        <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <file value="C:\Error.log"/>
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR"/>
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-2p %c %method - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change **log4net.Appender.FileAppender** to **log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender**.

```
<appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
```

Answer (score 5):

log4net has a feature in its configuration file where it tries to read Configuration name tags from the config file and locates them as writable properties on the class (Logger/Appender etc..) using reflection

see http://mperlstein.blogspot.com/2012/04/log4net-configuration-trouble.html, I answered and explained this there.

Comment: in that blog you didn't really provide a solution for issue

Comment: The quick and abrasive answer:  If an `<appender>` node in the log4net configuration XML contains children that aren't applicable to the appender type then log4net complains about those "extra" nodes.  Thanks to Mickey Perlstein for the details.

Comment: @AlexaAdrian I didn't provide a solution because this is just a way to (finally) understand the error you're getting and explain the backend of how log4net works, it doesn't mean there is a solution besides you debugging your XML because you have errors in there